# Why is a polar cone a closed set?

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. We define the polar cone as

$$Xº:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\,|\,\langle u,x\rangle\leq 0,\forall u\in X\}$$

How can I show that this set is closed?

If I fix some $u\in X$ then I have that $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\,|\,\langle u,x\rangle\leq 0\}$ is a closed halfspace; but if $X$ is infinite we can't conclude that the intersection of closed sets is also a closed set (as far as we are talking in terms of usual topology).

Comment: What does $u'x$ mean?

Comment: probably inter product with $u'$ the tranpose

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Usual product in $\mathbb{R^n}$. Edited.

Comment: why the intersection of closed sets is not a close set?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, please edit also the inner product also in the second set.

Comment: @dmtri It's done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, your argument works: $X^0$ is closed because it can be expressed as an intersection of closed sets.

Answer (score 8):

> if  is infinite we can't conclude that the intersection of closed sets is also a closed set (as far as we are talking in terms of usual topology).

Yes you can. One of the axioms of topology is that *any* union of open sets is open. (This is easy to show directly for the standard topology on a metric space).

Taking complements, you get that *any* intersection of closed sets is closed.